# character arrays and pointers basic confusion

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, pointers

I am a beginner in pointers. after completing integer arrays and pointers i shifted to character arrays and pointers. i expected the same results but its weird.

```
int main() {    
    char chararray[20]="Char Array";      
    void printarray(char *);    
    void printarraydirect(char * );

    printf("Passing chararray to funtion printarray\n");    
    printarray(chararray);        
    printf("Printing directly as c in printarraydirect function");        
    printarraydirect(chararray);

     return 0;
}

void printarray(char *c){        
    int i=0;    
    //while(c[i]!= ' ')-----------------------> checks for empty space        
    while(c[i]!='\0')    
    {    
        printf("%c",c[i]);       
        i++;    
    }    
    printf("\n");    
}



void printarraydirect(char * c){        
    printf("Printing c-------------->");        
    printf("%s\n",c);        
    int i=0;        
    printf("Printing c[i]-------------->\n");
    // shows error here , if so why didnt it show me error in printarray function. and why didnt it print the whole array when printed c in printarray function..

    printf("%s\n" c[i]);

}
```

Comment: You're defining your function inside `main()`? why?

Comment: `printf("%s\n" c[i]);` is not the same as `printf("%c",c[i]);`

Comment: last line should have to be `printf("%c\n" c[i]);` ,because it is only single character.

Comment: Do not declare prototypes inside main func, please.

Comment: Also observe that you need not specify the length `20` for `chararray` (the compiler sets the length according to the string literal you initialize it with if you leave the `[]` empty).

Comment: And the commented out `while(c[i] != ' ')` is incorrect unless the function has a precondition that the string _must_ contain a space; if a string without a space is passed, this would run past the end of the string.

Comment: Also, why C++ tag, it is not the same language as C. Choose one and only tag that - I'm assuming from the code that this is C, not C++.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're missing a comma on the line `printf("%s\n" c[i]);`. Secondly, `c[i]` is a single `char` (the element type of your array), hence the `%s` formatting is incorrect - it should be `%c` to print a single character. Or if you wish to print the entire string from that point onwards, you need to pass the address of that element (`&c[i]`), but in this case that is the same as `c` since `i` is zero.

Comment: sorry for the mistake over there. consider an int array, int a[5];int *p=a; then a[i] and *(a+i) will return value and &a[i] and a+i will return address.if so , then in my case why not printing c return me the address of just 1st character but it  returns the whole array .

Answer (score 0):

Basically `%s` format specifier expects an address to print to the output stream and it prints until it finds the NULL character(`\0`). Here when you give simply `c` the base address of the array is passed as the argument. But when you give `c[i]` it is the value located at the location (base address + index) i.e, addressOf(c) + valueOf(i).

Comment: then what is the way to print the address of each character in printarraydirect ??

Comment: If you want to print "address" of each character then you should use a "for" loop and the printf function should print the address like (printf("%d", &c[i])). this will print the address of each character. you can use long double format specifier too.

Comment: Thanks Tamil selvan.in c++ , if i print &a[0] it prints Char Array and if i print &a[2] it prints   ar Array,.why so? and in c++ how to print address??

Comment: @Jagdeesh I dont understand what r u asking? can u elaborate?